Which is more efficient between Socket.io or WebSockets raw with Redis Pub/Sub?
I currently have an application that uses Socket.IO to send notifications in real time (using server-side Python). We have about 30 instances of the service that handles these websockets. However, we have had problems with this functionality, so we have decided to migrate the websockets part directly to Go. In Go there is no good support for socket.io so we decided to use Gorilla Websockets. For the rooms concept, we decided to use Redis pub/sub. The idea then is that a websocket is established between the Frontend and Backend for each user, the backend subscribes to the channels necessary for each user and each message received from the channels is delivered to the frontend through the websocket connection. Likewise, the different microservices of the system that perform actions are connected to Redis and publish messages in the channel that is necessary. So, the architecture now would be something like this:

(Previously, socket.io rooms were simply used, But also with AsyncRedisManager)
Some additional considerations:

It is expected to have about 1000 active users at a time
Each user needs to listen to approximately 50 Redis channels.
In most channels messages are not published constantly, but in around 25% of them they are published every second.

The problem is that I previously mistakenly thought that socket.io used a redis channel for each room but I'm not sure about that now. As I see the configuration, only one channel is used. I'm afraid that my new implementation in which more channels are now created will end up being less efficient. Is the new design a commonly used model? Does it make sense? With the context provided, does this seem like a good solution?

Forgive me, but a few of those assumptions seem... off. As per the 1% rule, 1000 concurrent users would translate to a user base of 10 million users. Are you sure with your numbers? As for the other numbers: We'd be talking about 12500 messages per second, give and take. Say 15000. Basically idling for any decent pub/sub setup. Also, I ask myself what the Redis and all around rather complicated setup is good for. With so few calls, you could simply use direct requests from your backend to the micro services and safe you some headaches.

Thanks for your answer. It is an application used by a company, so the number of users is given because they must use it, it is not something that has users who decide or not to use it. As I understand it... you don't see any problem in these numbers for redis, correct?

Regarding why use redis, there are channels that are shared by multiple users (for example that refer to departments). So there are many users who must receive the message in the websocket connection when something happens in that department... then suppose that in microservice "x" a change was made in the "sales" department, from that microservice a message is published in the redis "sales" channel and all connections that are listening to the "sales" channel in the backend will receive that message from the channel and transmit it to the FrontEnd.

Still, my assertion stands: 15k msg/s is a relatively small amount. I'd be more concerned to scale the backend part horizontally.

Ok, thank you very much, I honestly had no idea if it was a little or a lot. The BackEnd scales horizontally without problem because they are stateless websockets. If the number of users grew a lot the "challenge" would be to scale Redis, but this was not a problem thanks to Sharded Pub/Sub since Redis 7 that allows me to do this with a Redis cluster. Thanks again.

I assume you meant that I should first horizontally scale the BackEnd.  Yes, you are right.  I just did tests and indeed before having to think about scaling Redis I will have to scale the BackEnd.
